# Progressive Web App with ReactJS combination

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

When I search this in Google, I'm getting more results regarding progressive web apps with angular, than react. Why is this the case?

I'm in the beginning stages of learning ReactJS, but I eventually want to understand PWA as well. Are these two completely different? Is it possible to build an entire scalable application using these two? I'm learning that the popular stack is Node + React + MongoDB. Does adding PWA benefit this or is there no point?

Is progressive web app still a thing? Is it here to stay for a long time or is it already a thing in the past? Just looking at the tags in stackoverflow, its not being talked much.

Comment: MERN Stack is the technology that you use to develop the application, PWA being a methodology you can follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of progressive web app is not limited to any javascript front end framework.

> A Progressive Web App (PWA) is a web app that uses modern web
>   capabilities to deliver an app-like experience to users. These apps
>   meet certain requirements, are deployed to servers,
>   accessible through URLs, and indexed by search engines.

So it can be web application made using simple vanilla javascript / angular / react / vue or any other.

To consider your application be PWA it should meet following requirements :

> Progressive - Work for every user, regardless of browser choice,
>   because they are built with progressive enhancement as a core tenet.
>
> Responsive - Fit any form factor, desktop, mobile, tablet, or whatever
>   is next.
>
> Connectivity independent - Enhanced with service workers to work
>   offline or on low quality networks.
>
> App-like - Use the app-shell model to provide app-style navigation and
>   interactions.
>
> Fresh - Always up-to-date thanks to the service worker update process.
>
> Safe - Served via HTTPS to prevent snooping and ensure content has not
>   been tampered with.
>
> Discoverable - Are identifiable as “applications” thanks to W3C
>   manifests and service worker registration scope allowing search
>   engines to find them.
>
> Re-engageable - Make re-engagement easy through features like push
>   notifications.
>
> Installable - Allow users to “keep” apps they find most useful on
>   their home screen without the hassle of an app store.
>
> Linkable - Easily share via URL and not require complex installation.

For more information visit the [Google developer guideline for PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)